# Docker Desktop stuck at Starting

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I try to open Docker Desktop on my Windows 11 machine, it's just stuck at starting forever. I've tried restarting Docker and restarting my machine and none fixed it.

I have multiple containers running, all coming from a docker compose file of mine, and I am trying to fix this without having to reset docker to factory settings or deleting its data since I can't really afford to.

These are the logs in my `dockerd.log` file:

```
[2023-12-04T02:10:27.493754710Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:27.493564087Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
[2023-12-04T02:10:30.479512864Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:30.479302404Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
[2023-12-04T02:10:36.882299955Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:36.882120359Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
[2023-12-04T02:10:41.696052309Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:41.695922588Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox dce7553ab786b5fefaa95f5d3c90ab24c80b5251db25863511b071a4c2bbba68 (b5d3a6d1d4643900baff342c45377b1a768fd3d5cde7a2649b64182cb2c621f6)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:41.853799071Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:41.853642559Z" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint ac9da0d16b31c4a4b6706d39920d376400a6647d38abfb87edf1f0538be9a0d5 a54f8e058d61a4ac8b11f0f797c51e2f24351150ad38ee528903efb549029f33], retrying...."
[2023-12-04T02:10:42.053843696Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:42.053636202Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox e6ee35a9ac3d77523bead6c8f7c663798c5e5cca56811b06f755d7f3bdd1fd2a (69eff02309bf2a38d77013ba19281027c908bd60ae2faf7c990b058275d7b3f9)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:42.153807592Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:42.153527530Z" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint f09fc28598bf52fc5f06b85f6927f23ea8f4132ed8c4e9b3b8d85884ddc034d8 654cb742b752a44f218f7d2ecef0bc5175f0a7a0bc111bc65accae9edb746641], retrying...."
[2023-12-04T02:10:42.477363554Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:42.477157708Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox fcc6cd9198529f056a8512db752e647d3c74ea83f52489dbfaa359020d2f3342 (073966fdab8b1511cce5ca700a081df5ff609645c4f90f0807edcb54666ebc7a)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:42.664898605Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:42.664708719Z" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint f09fc28598bf52fc5f06b85f6927f23ea8f4132ed8c4e9b3b8d85884ddc034d8 02906517101c5fbd87263121a3742cbca9d20e8a493d359d0b44e65f34efb4f9], retrying...."
[2023-12-04T02:10:42.899554980Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:42.899425240Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 6f81f5f3c73e327157f83b86042bd5beb485f35a9d44ace9840c353a4c7e27b2 (0c73c24392f8c5512fc6af8bbd431342968de4a217ee9c40159b143e6fcbab91)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:43.020368940Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:43.020158129Z" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint f09fc28598bf52fc5f06b85f6927f23ea8f4132ed8c4e9b3b8d85884ddc034d8 788322abf0ce1b58d635756f66eceb15d443af453e0c1517a353bbaeee026d83], retrying...."
[2023-12-04T02:10:43.310803765Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:43.310584765Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 6fbf60297893e5db1db7e1789bc8b3afdd727aaa59f24866b0cde300e5e30337 (b6b528cba2694a222d81933287f18c094517bd25d8dba64bdd4f2b801a685935)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:43.409791897Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:43.409554751Z" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint f09fc28598bf52fc5f06b85f6927f23ea8f4132ed8c4e9b3b8d85884ddc034d8 cf4505e457edff2a065f834b7f570ef1576570d6a09cd7e473bb0372ed0d6300], retrying...."
[2023-12-04T02:10:43.588335346Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:43.588163350Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 77803ea476e36b618b5b0e8b847032406b072ae91eec626652e9abfc3e27eebc (e8a2a53acd9085bde7737f10486640f3c61ab8940463b0c46f687795c47a9d3e)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:43.687016628Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:43.686820516Z" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint f09fc28598bf52fc5f06b85f6927f23ea8f4132ed8c4e9b3b8d85884ddc034d8 18ba6cb46efd32fce48a96921e7f271d909b730d901efc73213c37e477ec8eb8], retrying...."
[2023-12-04T02:10:43.932386102Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:43.932240054Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 87f69e34dcadb24f8efdb7f5282a6c62eec9a6307b41b136a411b83a1cf8677d (74ea570799388ff838e25291412a848082b5f069cad0559506ab19510b070439)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:43.987915659Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:43.987764757Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 2782d3f85d4b496f75614fb66f09fc106284bd03d36aa943989f22bfa13fd17d (f3d1963a0954a32dd8fcd10527016f02c76e74c5ff4a2ecf83c42801f14d3023)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:44.098343727Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:44.098156161Z" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint f09fc28598bf52fc5f06b85f6927f23ea8f4132ed8c4e9b3b8d85884ddc034d8 a66eba39ac331d85cedf710f3caf446aadc06ff260fb6f4985b7ea5e36a4c922], retrying...."
[2023-12-04T02:10:44.276773616Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:44.276617059Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 6523ca82365c4e326071565933b4da2b492299086ac1b6af827154d9a3d71f67 (fcb9c5b3ba93638983e086d4dc19de463e9143daab9da8be8c642ed243335feb)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:44.321707922Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:44.321527879Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox f62bfda3e205408fe78fe36cc3de3f9bc2d84f5dc9a58515ea01b1fe89148936 (dccda855463afb36ed000a8da406e050e26f5ff71cd866cf5d9bafd8fc63391e)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:44.355737493Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:44.355568748Z" level=info msg="Removing stale endpoint homarr (a626d992afadafdc9b1c5e6fc871c592b7fa4513505070925abed299d3fc0ee6)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:44.497891487Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:44.497711701Z" level=info msg="Removing stale endpoint flaresolverr (2ff64b2dd16ee43f7aa77f2dfb891f77f56a7dd20a6a299586bbf9f0db9953f3)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:44.653640987Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:44.653451151Z" level=info msg="Removing stale endpoint sonarr (da5ccf3d4839aad2d79af1d2f5d866b4d2b78187b95fc32fc3ac0756988a12b0)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:44.854039426Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:44.853878065Z" level=info msg="Removing stale endpoint prowlarr (511ebcb7625e54be8cbef883f8c8e6a095976b2e3b2f6c61afe88fc656efe7a5)"
[2023-12-04T02:10:45.198299264Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:10:45.198087797Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
[2023-12-04T02:11:04.099195691Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:04.099010770Z" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 8989-8989: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8989 failed: port is already allocated"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.544187915Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.543942609Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.544219205Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.544022400Z" level=warning msg="Could not rollback container connection to network media-stack_media"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.544234313Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.544087033Z" level=error msg="fcb9c5b3ba93638983e086d4dc19de463e9143daab9da8be8c642ed243335feb: failed saving state on start failure: open /var/lib/docker/containers/fcb9c5b3ba93638983e086d4dc19de463e9143daab9da8be8c642ed243335feb/.tmp-config.v2.json3810281355: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.544243000Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.544136106Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.544245595Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.544177786Z" level=warning msg="Failed to delete sandbox e0ca3842e860210c47d3f54dff1f9dd66627452a726b059af30fbc766d42903c from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.616196165Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.616008679Z" level=error msg="failed to start container" container=fcb9c5b3ba93638983e086d4dc19de463e9143daab9da8be8c642ed243335feb error="failed to update store for object type *libnetwork.Endpoint: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.672886394Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.672714893Z" level=warning msg="Failed to delete host side interface (vethbf9ee13)'s link" error="no such device"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.672908967Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.672846222Z" level=error msg="dccda855463afb36ed000a8da406e050e26f5ff71cd866cf5d9bafd8fc63391e: failed saving state on start failure: open /var/lib/docker/containers/dccda855463afb36ed000a8da406e050e26f5ff71cd866cf5d9bafd8fc63391e/.tmp-config.v2.json1997542129: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.674076290Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.673996544Z" level=error msg="dccda855463afb36ed000a8da406e050e26f5ff71cd866cf5d9bafd8fc63391e cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: read-only file system: unknown"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.674088263Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.674037682Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.674094074Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.674052600Z" level=warning msg="error locating sandbox id d1dce33796479bfbbf3ee3515b27cbfbd729abb7eb456ed1884bb21e63b6d331: sandbox d1dce33796479bfbbf3ee3515b27cbfbd729abb7eb456ed1884bb21e63b6d331 not found"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.714311111Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.714169397Z" level=error msg="failed to start container" container=dccda855463afb36ed000a8da406e050e26f5ff71cd866cf5d9bafd8fc63391e error="failed to create endpoint homarr on network media-stack_media: failed to save bridge endpoint 1792a50 to store: failed to update bridge store for object type *bridge.bridgeEndpoint: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.766235281Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.766110643Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.766270173Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.766161480Z" level=warning msg="Failed to delete sandbox 7c710f658605175479c2cc8d0d470eb92e8ef403e699f64a1f0ef95e64563d85 from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.808942361Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.808826180Z" level=error msg="failed to start container" container=74ea570799388ff838e25291412a848082b5f069cad0559506ab19510b070439 error="driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint sonarr (91718d5eebd8f1051ed649f94d6258444855be9d6b461e75425a8919a503395c): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8989 failed: port is already allocated"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.977621585Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.977490746Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.982308383Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.982213732Z" level=warning msg="Not using native diff for overlay2, this may cause degraded performance for building images: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/opaque-bug-check2630561342: read-only file system" storage-driver=overlay2
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.982320205Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.982270771Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.982332789Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.982289436Z" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.982333891Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.982304545Z" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.982336737Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.982308142Z" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.982336877Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.982310797Z" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.982337678Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.982313863Z" level=warning msg="WARNING: daemon is not using the default seccomp profile"
[2023-12-04T02:11:10.982360993Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:10.982326988Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=1a79695 graphdriver=overlay2 version=24.0.6
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.052965975Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.052750807Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.331357543Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.331236693Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=e8a2a53acd9085bde7737f10486640f3c61ab8940463b0c46f687795c47a9d3e module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.331380802Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.331317531Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=69eff02309bf2a38d77013ba19281027c908bd60ae2faf7c990b058275d7b3f9 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.337956745Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.337888911Z" level=error msg="69eff02309bf2a38d77013ba19281027c908bd60ae2faf7c990b058275d7b3f9 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: read-only file system: unknown"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.337968307Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.337931222Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.337974599Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.337950408Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.338012200Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.337977109Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.343890508Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.343789650Z" level=warning msg="driver failed revoking external connectivity on endpoint bazarr (39b699b1f9fe1e8eef5b3aab3b1433fa70b77f44650072b7bd43f1e8f5800778): failed to update bridge endpoint 39b699b to store: failed to update bridge store for object type *bridge.bridgeEndpoint: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.358833449Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.358735117Z" level=error msg="e8a2a53acd9085bde7737f10486640f3c61ab8940463b0c46f687795c47a9d3e cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: read-only file system: unknown"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.358856933Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.358784000Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.358864167Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.358802936Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.358867423Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.358815329Z" level=warning msg="failed to get endpoint_count map from store: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.364942530Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.364870473Z" level=warning msg="driver failed revoking external connectivity on endpoint radarr (9f3a391758cd507d112217181591379a25123ba3c914a55464763ccef19940c8): failed to update bridge endpoint 9f3a391 to store: failed to update bridge store for object type *bridge.bridgeEndpoint: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: read-only file system"
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.369515927Z][dockerd][I] open /var/lib/docker/buildkit/containerdmeta.db: read-only file system
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.369520766Z][dockerd][I] time="2023-12-04T02:11:11.369482278Z" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
[2023-12-04T02:11:11.405931294Z][dockerd][I] EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues after upgrade (remove and install) my docker to the last version. For me, the issue was that the Docker daemon failed to start because it could not create the default bridge network. The reason for this is that the docker0 interface is already bound to the trusted zone in firewalld. To fix this, you can either remove the trusted zone or specify a different bridge interface when you start the Docker daemon.

Here are the steps on how to fix this:

```
Remove the trusted zone in firewalld:

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --remove-interface docker0
firewall-cmd --reload

Start the Docker daemon:

systemctl start docker
```